# How to retrieve all columns from a table but one column should look up the value in another table (SQL-server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, primary-key

I have two tables in a SQL DB, `Item` and `ItemPlacement`. I need all the data from `Item` but there is one column (`ItemPlace`), which has a key value instead of the name of the item placement. The table `ItemPlacement` holds the corresponding key in the ID column and the name of the placement in the `PlacementName` column. How do I get all the records from Item but with replaced values in the column `ItemPlace` from the column `ItemPlacement.PlacementName`? None of the examples I have come across writes `SELECT * FROM Item ...` Which Id really need as I don't know the numbers of columns in the `Item` table (using the statement dynamically on other databases).

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`/`ON`.

Comment: Instead of trying to explain a data problem in words, use SQL Fiddle (or similar) to create the tables, add some sample data and your initial attempt at a query. That way people here can copy and paste that out, tweak it, and post an answer back. You'll be much more likely to get an answer if you do that work in advance.

Answer (score 1):

basic example

```
SELECT abc.col1, abc.col2, def.col3
from [table a] abc
join [table b] def
   on def.col = abc.col
```